# setting model content in back bone using underscore external template

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

this is my backbone code ,where iam using a underscore template,it is  working fine now i am trying to make that template external and load from there

this is my sample backbone code

Backbone Application

```
<div class="list"></div>

<script id="personTemplate" type="text/template">
    <strong><%= name %></strong> (<%= age %>) - <%= occupation %>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Guest User',
        age: 23,
        occupation: 'worker'
    }
});

var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
   tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template( $('#personTemplate').html()),

    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});
var person = new Person;  // a person object created...
//person.set('name', 'abhi');
var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
personView.el   // ---->; You can call this method and it will display the view..
$(document.body).html(personView.el);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

what is really need is that i will place this template  `<strong><%= name %></strong> (<%= age %>) - <%= occupation %>` in a external file. i dont know much about its extension,i think it can be a html file and load the template from there ,i researched about it and find some sample code  and tried some thing  like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_.mixin({templateFromUrl: function (url, data, settings) {
    var templateHtml = "";
    this.cache = this.cache || {};

    if (this.cache[url]) {
        templateHtml = this.cache[url];
        alert(templateHtml);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                templateHtml = data;
                alert(templateHtml);
            }
        });

        this.cache[url] = templateHtml;
    }

    return _.template(templateHtml, data, settings);
}});
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Guest User',
        age: 23,
        occupation: 'worker'
    }
});

var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
   tagName: 'li',

   template:_.templateFromUrl("templatefile1.html", {"name": "value","age":10}) ,
   // template:_.templateFromUrl("templatefile1.html", this.model.toJSON()) ,
  //template: _.template( $('#personTemplate').html()),
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
    alert(this.template);
        this.$el.html( this.template);
    }
});
var person = new Person;  // a person object created...
//person.set('name', 'abhi');
var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
personView.el   // ---->; You can call this method and it will display the view..
$(document.body).html(personView.el);
</script>
```

but when  i am calling  teemplate  like  this `template:_.templateFromUrl("templatefile1.html", {"name": "value","age":10}) ,`
it is working 
but when i trying to pass the pass model to that template   like this

template:_.templateFromUrl("templatefile1.html", this.model.toJSON())

i am getting exception  like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined
```

how can i resolve this issue

Comment: Careful with `$(document.body).html(personView.el);`, looks like you're storing `<script>`s inside your `<body>` and `$('body').html(...)` clears `<body>` before adding the new stuff.

Comment: @  mu is too short 1 thanks  for your thoughts,it is just a sample code

Comment: @ mu is too short  i have tried that but nor working can you please provide the code?

Comment: What specifically have you tried? What specifically went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying something like this:

```
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    template: _.templateFromUrl("templatefile1.html", this.model.toJSON()),
    //...
});
```

What do you think `this` is in that context? It certainly won't be an instance of your view since no instances have been made yet. `this` is going to be `window` at the level and `window` won't have a useful `model` property. You need to defer that call until you have an instance of your view created with a `model` property.

You could make `template` a method:

```
template: function() {
    return _.templateFromUrl('templatefile1.html', this.model.toJSON());
}
```

and then call it at the appropriate time:

```
render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    return this; // <----- Standard practise so you can x.append(v.render().el)
}
```

I'd recommend against using `async:false` with `$.ajax` though, that's a nasty thing to do to people. Instead, you should hand `templateFromUrl` a callback function that it can call when the template has come in from the server.

If you're going to be doing this sort of thing a lot then you could add a `template` function to a base view:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: function() {
        // This assumes that you have exactly one of `this.model` and
        // `this.collection`, you can do other things here if that doesn't
        // work in your world.
        var data_source = this.model || this.collection;
        return _.templateFromUrl(this.template_name, data_source.toJSON());
    }
});
```

and then use it your `PersonView`:

```
var PersonView = BaseView.extend({
    template_name: 'templatefile1.html',
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    //...
});
```

Comment: -how can i make that templateFromUrl a callback function can you please provide the code?

Comment: Just add another argument to `templateFromUrl` to hold the callback and then call that callback inside the AJAX `success` handler. If the template is already in the cache then call the callback directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the model reusable, and define a url:

```
 var PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Untitled',
        age: 0,
        occupation: null,
    },
    url: "/somefile.json"
});
```

Create a listener for model changes inside the view, and fetch the model:

```
    initialize: function(options){
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        this.model.fetch();
    }
```

Create a new model, then pass it to a new view:

```
var person = new PersonModel();
var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
```